# Is geth --rpc --support-dao-fork still valid

Tags: go-ethereum, dao, solo-mining

I have the blockchain synced, and then tried to run  geth --rpc --support-dao-fork. I got a message saying that --support-dao-fork is unsupported command. 
So I have run geth --rpc --syncmode "fast" --verbosity 3 --cache=1024 and then
Running etherminer -G from cpp-etherum it downloads the DAG and starts to mine. 
geth is committing the work to the blockchain.

Has the --support option been depreciated or am I mining ETC instead of post fork Eth by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On hard fork the PR [2813](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2814) was introduced to support the network split and  those two options were added.

> This PR implements setting the --support-dao-fork and
>   --oppose-dao-fork flags. As of now they only modify a single database entry specifying whether the current default behavior should change.

Nowadays both options were removed and the official client [doesn't support ETC](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14401#issuecomment-298642814)